# How to convert a hex string to an unsigned long?

Tags: c++, mfc, hex, data-conversion, unsigned-long-long-int

I have following hex value

```
CString str;
str = T("FFF000");
```

How to convert this in to an `unsigned long`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{

    std::string s("0xFFF000");
    unsigned long value;
    std::istringstream iss(s);
    iss >> std::hex >> value;
    std::cout << value << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `std::setbase(16)` or `std::hex`?

Answer (score 12):

You can use `strtol` function which works on regular C strings. It converts a string to a long using a specified base:

```
long l = strtol(str, NULL, 16);
```

details and good example:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/strtol/

Comment: I think he might actually want `stroul` or `stoul` since he wants an `unsigned long`.